# Custom Tab Bar Menu with horizontal swipe

Tags: swift, xcode

Just a quick question regarding implementation.

I am trying to recreate this:

https://i.imgur.com/lFXKFXl.mp4

I am wondering if I have to do it from scratch using a UICollectionView, there's a built-in Xcode method, or there is a library online somewhere.

Note: I am not trying to create a tab bar menu at the bottom, but rather at the top underneath the navigation controller navbar with horizontal swipe features. Instagram also has this underneath the search tab.

Thank you!

Comment: My suggestion is you can work with some library..these are some options https://github.com/search?l=Swift&o=desc&q=tabbar&s=stars&type=Repositories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `UIScrollView` and add child viewcontrollers to it. I made an extension to UIViewController that easily allows you to create a swipe view.

```
extension UIViewController {
    public func addViewControllerToContainer(viewController: UIViewController, count: CGFloat = 0, container: UIScrollView, heightDecrease: CGFloat = 0, startIndex: CGFloat = 0) {

        let multiplier: CGFloat = count

        addChildViewController(viewController)
        container.addSubview(viewController.view)
        container.contentSize.width += viewController.view.frame.width
        container.contentSize.height = viewController.view.frame.height - heightDecrease

        container.frame = CGRect(x: viewController.view.frame.origin.x, y: viewController.view.frame.origin.y, width: viewController.view.frame.width, height: viewController.view.frame.height - heightDecrease)
        container.frame.origin.y += heightDecrease

        container.contentOffset.x = container.frame.width * startIndex

        viewController.view.frame.size.width = container.frame.width
        viewController.view.frame.size.height = container.frame.height
        viewController.view.frame.size.height -= heightDecrease
        viewController.view.frame.origin.x = container.frame.width * multiplier

    }

    public func addViewControllersToContainer(viewControllers: [UIViewController], container: UIScrollView, heightDecrease: CGFloat = 0, startIndex: CGFloat) {
        var count: CGFloat = 0
        for viewController in viewControllers {
            addViewControllerToContainer(viewController: viewController, count: count, container: container, heightDecrease: heightDecrease, startIndex: startIndex)
            count += 1
        }
    }    
}


class MainSwipeViewController: UIViewController {

    let viewControllers: [UIViewController] = [VC1, VC2, VC3] // view controllers swiped between
    let startIndex: CGFloat = 0  // which viewController to begin at (0 means first)

    let mainScrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        scrollView.bounces = false
        scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        return scrollView
    }()

    private func addViewControllers(_ vc: UIViewController, viewControllers: [UIViewController], startIndex: CGFloat = 0) {
        view.addSubview(mainScrollView)
        addViewControllersToContainer(viewControllers: viewControllers, container: mainScrollView, startIndex: startIndex)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addViewControllers(self, viewControllers: viewControllers, startIndex: startIndex)
    }
}
```

As for the tabbar menu, you can easily create that by implementing `UIScrollViewDelegate` in `MainSwipeViewController`

```
extension MainSwipeViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.x / view.frame.width       
    }
}
```

`contentOffset` is the interval of your swipe and increases by one everytime you swipe. This will help you animate the blue bar in your menu.

Answer (score 1):

You can animate your blue bar in following way

```
 func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
  blueBarViewLeadingConstraint.constant = scrollView.contentOffset.x / (scrollView.bounds.width / (TabBarView.frame.size.width / numberOfTab)) 
}
```